# Treemap comparator by value

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator, treemap

```
SortedMap<Integer, Long> newMap = new TreeMap(new MyComparator(result));
newMap.putAll(result);
System.out.println("new map ---> " + newMap);
```

**MyComparator.java**

```
package com.example.admin.app;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;

class MyComparator implements Comparator {

    Map map;
    public MyComparator(Map map){
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare (Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Long) map.get(o2)).compareTo((Long) map.get(o1));
    }
}
```

While using treemap comparator, if values of 2 keys are same, comparator is considering only 1st value and ignoring second one.

Eg: Unsorted map -> {2=93085, 1=93254, 4=92928, 9=93164, 8=93085}

my actual result for the code written: {1=93254, 9=93164, 8=93085, 4=92928}

I need output like --> {1=93254, 9=93164, 8=93085, 2=93085, 4=92928}

Since key 2 and 8 have same values (93085), I'm getting only one. Someone please help.

Comment: what do you mean `I'm getting only one` can you show the code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In order for us to help you, can you post the comparator code you are using?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Deadpool he's losing one of the input values because one value is overwriting another one where the comparator is returning equal (i.e. 0)

Comment: The `Comparator` utilized by `TreeMap` compares keys, not values. There must be something else in your code that's causing this issue.

Comment: @JacobG. I think if the Comparator returns 0, the TreeMap will interpret that as the same key value, and replace the value that was there before with the new one

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That seemed to be the obvious answer but as @Jacob G. pointed out, it is indeed not possible to only compare values in a `TreeMap`. The question is missing way too much details to be actually answerable.

Comment: @ControlAltDel indeed, that’s precisely [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) for `TreeMap`: “*a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal.*” and it’s a general contract for `Map` to never contain two equal keys.

Comment: @Holger, keys are not equal. Only values are equal

Comment: Keys are equal when the comparator says that they are equal. That’s precisely what the cited text says.

Comment: But keys (2 and 8) are not equal. Values of them are 93085, which is same for both.

Comment: Again, keys are equal *when the comparator says that they are equal*. You have implemented a comparator which says that these keys are equal when their value is equal. You get what you have asked for.

Comment: Ok so how can I resolve it? I'm using Java 7

Answer (score 1):

It's a property of the `TreeMap` to treat keys as equal when the comparator reports them as equal (and maps do not support multiple equal keys in general).

As [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/util/TreeMap.html) says:

> …a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal.

If you want to prevent the keys from disappearing when there is no ordering between them, you have to add a secondary ordering, to be used when the primary ordering considers them as equal. Since your map has comparable keys in the first place, you can utilize their natural order to get the desired result:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    final Map<Integer, Long> map;
    public MyComparator(Map<Integer, Long> map){
        this.map = map;
    }
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        int c = Long.compare(map.get(o2), map.get(o1));
        return c != 0? c: o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
}
```

```
Map<Integer, Long> result = new HashMap<>();
result.put(2, 93085L);
result.put(1, 93254L);
result.put(4, 92928L);
result.put(9, 93164L);
result.put(8, 93085L);

SortedMap<Integer, Long> newMap = new TreeMap<>(new MyComparator(result));
newMap.putAll(result);
// new map ---> {1=93254, 9=93164, 8=93085, 2=93085, 4=92928}
System.out.println("new map ---> " + newMap);
```

Alternatively, you may use a `LinkedHashMap` which maintains the insertion order and fill it using a sorted list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(result.keySet());
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator(result));
Map<Integer, Long> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(Integer i: list) newMap.put(i, result.get(i));
System.out.println("new map ---> " + newMap);
```

Both approaches produce a map with the desired iteration order. Which is more suitable depends on how it is subsequently used.

Since sorting a list does not eliminate duplicates, it would also work with your initial comparator, though I would make it type safe:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    final Map<?, Long> map;
    public MyComparator(Map<?, Long> map){
        this.map = map;
    }
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return Long.compare(map.get(o2), map.get(o1));
    }
}
```

But then, the relative order of entries with the same value is unspecified.